# Ad not showing up in emulator

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am using following code in my WP7 app to display the test ad by Windows marketplace. When I run the emulator, no ad is shown. What is the matter ?

```
 <my:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80" ApplicationId="test_client" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,550,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Are you sure it has space to be displayed? Try to disable the autocollapse property and subscribe to the error event.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior. The ad is not displayed in your emulator. Here is a picture to illustrate my point -

[Image http://gowthams.in/etc/wp7.PNG](http://gowthams.in/etc/wp7.PNG)

That being said, make sure to specify the width, height, Ad Unit ID and application ID correctly.